# PHP script taking too much time

Tags: php, curl

I have a script that fetches data from another API. The script is taking too much time while retrieving data from API around 1 hour and 30 minutes. The purpose of this script is to copy the reviews and send them to another account. The script first gathers the feedbacks and then based on order id obtained from feedback, iterates that feedback array and then performs curl request to some other API to obtain some data based on that order id. But that curl requests in loop taking too much time to return data. 
The feedback are 3000 around. 
How can i handle script to return data sooner?

```
$feedbacks = getFeedbacks();

        if(count($feedbacks)>0){
            foreach($feedbacks as $feedback){
                $getData($feedback->order_id);
            }
        }
function getData($orderId)
{
    $orderId = $orderId;

        $api = "api address here";


    $curl = curl_init($api);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
    $json = json_decode($curl_response);

}
```

Comment: how much data are you working with? Divide total time (in seconds) / total amount of data to get seconds per data row - if it's below 1 second you have nothing to worry about - if it's relatively high (>= 5 seconds) then something is holding the script back (maybe the actual connecting for example)

Comment: lets see : assuming `api address here` is over an internet connexion, possibly https, and an average call-setup/call/transfer/call-teardown time of 1.5 second, yep ! 4500 seconds it is !

Comment: Yep your at the mercy of the network and whatever 3rd party API that is.  You may be able to run multiple processes against the API at the same time, but most ppl frown on you hammering their servers.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs the data is around 3000 and script taking 2 hour time. I want to optimize it.

Comment: so 5400 (1hr 30min) / 3000 = 1.8. 1.8 seconds is an expected speed - not much you can do - sorry bud :/

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs so can't optimize it?

Comment: not that I can see that wouldn't be micro optimisation - maybe only grab the data you need rather than everything (e.g. api might return full order details, when you only wanted order_customer_id for example) .. if thats in your control

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs thanks for explanation but unfortunately API is not in my control.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is when u call curl in loop the second call need  the first to complete then the second can start and that take long time 
To fix this u can use (pclose popen)  the script will pass them in background and in second script u can manage your return data:

First script :

```
<?php 
$feedbacks = getFeedbacks();

        if(count($feedbacks)>0){
            foreach($feedbacks as $feedback){
                $getData($feedback->order_id);
            }
        }
function getData($orderId)
{
    $orderId = $orderId;

     pclose(popen('sudo /usr/bin/php  /home/secondscript.php -o '.$orderId." >/dev/null &", 'r'));

}
```

Second script :

```
<?php


 $command_line_args= getopt("o:");

 $orderId=$command_line_args["o"];

   $api = "api address here";


    $curl = curl_init($api);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
    $json = json_decode($curl_response);

    {here u can use the json return ..}
```